# Prefix and suffix for endnotes and differing in-text endnote formatting?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting, footnote

Currently, I aim to use endnotes for practical reasons on a space-restricted paper.

Already I know how to realize endnotes and watched [this genius YT tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gpYH-SKw7A) video.

The problem is: How do I achieve a `[1]` display vs. the current `1` display?

**The author of the video already hints that this is impossible to realize automatically**, but is this still the case with Word Preview 2013? (I of course tried and it sadly seems so.)

Second problem: I want to use a different formatting for the "endnotes" within the text, i.e. writing a sentence:

> "The apple doesn't fall far from the tree"^1

i.e. using superscript and / or no [...] brackets.

But it seems ***unlike*** with footnotes, endnotes are displayed in the same manner?
Why is that? Is it a little confusing and disappointing.

**Initial research done:**

- Watched the video, googled, tried in Word 2013, searched SE

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way of doing that. Just do the advanced find and substitute, leave the search input blank, choose style corresponding to the footnote reference (it will find all text in that style) and replace that by for example [^&], which will result in [1], [2] and so on.

Answer (score -1):

With Word 2016 for Mac it's possibile to add prefixes and suffixes for footnote. Just Open "advanced find and substitute" window, type "^f" with uppercase format then type "prefix" (what do yo want) "^&" "suffix" (what do you want, and click substitute all. Now all the footnote anchors are with your indicated prefixes and suffixes.